# Why is the ids in my jpa hibernate postgres database skipping id values?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I have these tables that are autogenerated by JPA and Hibernate on startup with these spring configuration.

This is my application.yml config:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://postgres-cinema:5432/postgres"
    username: "postgres"
    password: ""
    driver-class-name: "org.postgresql.Driver"
  jpa:
    database: "postgresql"
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: "update"
```

These are my Entity classes:

```
@Entity
class Cinema(

    @get:Id @get:GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null,

    @get:NotBlank @get:Size(max = 128)
    var name: String,

    @get:NotBlank @get:Size(max = 128)
    var location: String? = null,

    @get:OneToMany(mappedBy = "cinema", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var rooms: MutableSet<Room> = mutableSetOf()
)

@Entity
class Room(

    @get:Id @get:GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null,

    @get:NotBlank @get:Size(max = 128)
    var name: String,

    @get:ElementCollection
    @get:NotNull
    var seats: MutableSet<String>,

    @get:ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @get:JoinColumn(name = "cinema_id")
    var cinema: Cinema? = null
)
```

When i'm creating a new Cinema it gets the id of 1
Next i'm creating a new Room, and it gets the id of 2.

Am i doing something rong with the entity tables? and aren't these supposed to be independent table with their own ids?

Comment: You might use sequence in your database to provide you your Ids.

Comment: Something like `@Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_sequence_name")
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_sequence_name", sequenceName = "id_sequence_sql_name", allocationSize = 1)
 @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
 private Long id;`